Why can't I parent the mesh to the armature with automatic weights?
I'm trying to create an animation of an alien hand picking up a plate. After watching some tutorials, I downloaded a free model of an alien hand and rigged it. Every time I attempt to parent the mesh and the armature with automatic weights, Blender freezes and I have to force quit the program.
I don't know how much of this is relevant but I'm pretty new to Blender and this is my first rigging project...
-I'm working on a surface pro laptop that is probably not ideal for Blender and there's 45 GB of free space.
-The only projects I've made so far include a small low poly scene, and the Blender donuts that lots of people make (without the animation), and one project with just two small objects. Not sure how much this affects memory within Blender??
-I've gone through and deleted any objects I don't need within my project in case it is a memory issue with Blender.

When I try to parent the two, I'm in Object Mode and first select the mesh. Then select the armature and press ctrl-p and try to select 'with automatic weights' and that's when Blender freezes every time.

Here's the wireframe view of the original model. After looking around online, it seemed like maybe the mesh could be causing the problem and I should retopologize it so it's more simple. The original model had over 72,000 faces. So I retopologized it using a voxel size of .005. I also added a decimate modifier 'de-subdivide' option without applying it, per someone else's suggestion and was able to lower the number of faces to just over 3,400. But Blender continues to freeze up at that step every time.
I'm really stuck. Any help would appreciated.

Using a Remesh modifier with a 0.005 voxel size is quite overkill for your mesh, or for most mesh to be honest. That's how the default cube would look like:

You need to zoom to macro level to even see the individual faces...
Using a decimate modifier can be a nice way to reduce polycount, but weights are done on the vertices from the raw mesh. So if you didn't apply your remesh or decimate, you are still asking Blender to work on the original mesh, not the one with modifiers.
To be honest, I doubt you would get a hard time making a manual retopology even though you are new to Blender. It would be pretty fast to do, would give you full control lover how the mesh deforms, and nothing prevents you from adding a subdivision modifier after the armature deform modifier.
You could go from something like this:

With that kind of model, handling weights is easy, performance when deforming with an armature is optimal.

Thanks for responding! That's good to know about the modifier. And I wasn't aware you could manually retopologize. I'm assuming that's a different process than using voxel remesher or the quad remesh? Should I use the decimate modifier to drastically reduce what's already there? Or what do you suggest I use for search terms to look up a tutorial on how to do that? I'll definitely give it a shot!

using modifiers to retopo is a quick and dirty way, mainly used for unimportant static non-deformed objects. Manually modeling the final model is the most common way to for any important model or ones that are to be deformed.  Making a full tutorial on retopology here would be out of topic and overkill. There are plenty of resources everywhere on the web. In your case it's a simple hand with no high detail to worry about so you could very much free-style it as I did. You could also look up for pictures of nice low poly animation-grade hands topologies and try to replicate.

Oooohhhh, I get it now! You're suggesting I just model the hand myself based off of the model I downloaded. I'll give it a shot. Thank you for your help!

I ended up reloading my model into Blender and remaking the armature. Even though I didn't exactly follow your suggestion, everything you've said is applicable to what the problem was. I did end up using voxel remesh with a voxel size of .09. This drastically lowered the number of vertices to around 4,000. I did try applying the decimate modifier but it didn't make enough of a difference to use it. You were correct that by not applying it, Blender was still trying to parent the original mesh. I just wanted to add this info here for anyone that might run into the same problem.

4k triangles for such a simple shape is still high and unnecessary. My rough hand probably had like 500 quads / 1000 tris.

I'm sure you're right. But I mostly want to just finish my project because I'm almost done. So I'll just keep things as is for now. But I would like to try your suggestion next time instead of using a model with a bajillion faces that slows down Blender.
